# Django: Not able to clickable url

Tags: django, django-templates

What I have done is I have shown all models in one view. With this logic:

```
def cylinderListView(request):
    cylinder=CylinderEntry.objects.all().values('cylinderId','EntryDate','gasName','Status','Availability','issuecylinder__userName','issuecylinder__issueDate','returncylinder__returnDate')
    
    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html',{'cylinder':cylinder})
```

And in my cylinderList template, I set cylinder as clickable URL which redirects me to cylinderDetailPage, it was working fine until I have added values in cylinderListview

here is cylinderList.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<div>
<h1>Cylinder list</h1>

<div class='centerstage'>
    
        <div class="post">
            <table border="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%"  >
                <thead>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Cylinder Id</th>
                        <th height="50" width="50">Date</th>
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Gas Type</th>
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Status</th>
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Availability</th>
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Issued Date</th>
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Customer</th>
                        <th  height="50" width="50">Return Date</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {%for cy in cylinder%}
                    <tr align="center">
                        
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50"><a href="{{cy.get_absolute_url}}">{{cy.cylinderId}}</a></td>
               
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                
                width="50">{{cy.EntryDate}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.gasName}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">
                    {{cy.Status}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.Availability}}</td>
              
                    
                    <td align="center" height="10" width="50">{{cy.issuecylinder__issueDate}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" width="50">{{cy.issuecylinder__userName}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" width="50">{{cy.returncylinder__returnDate}}</td>                
            </tr>
```

{% endfor %}

```
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

here is all models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','available'), 
    
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="Available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinderId)


class IssueCylinder(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',to_field='cylinderId',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=False)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.userName) 


class ReturnCylinder(models.Model):
    fill=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty'),
    ('refill','Refill')
    ]

    ava=[
    ('yes','YES'),
    ('no','NO')
    ]
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_return=models.ForeignKey('IssueCylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    returnDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=fill)
    availability=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=ava)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

            if self.availability=='YES' or self.availability=='yes':
                CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Available')
            else:
                CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Unavailable')
                if self.status=='refill' or self.status=='Refill':
                    CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Refill')


        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinder)
```

How do I get cylinderId clickable url after this query?

Comment: Show your template too.

Comment: When you use `.values()` on a QuerySet it returns a set of dicts rather than a set of `CylinderEntry` objects. So when you try to access `get_absolute_url()` for each object in your template it no longer works because they're now dicts, rather than `CylinderEntry`'s

Comment: @elyas Thanks for your answer but what should I do to access get_absolute_url()? or there any other way that I m able to display all fields in view also able to access get_absolute_url() ?

Comment: Instead of using `values()` you could access your related (foreign key) objects as attributes e.g. `{{ cy.issuecylinder.userName }}`. And use `prefetch_related()` on your query so you're not making a database call every time. Or you could keep using `values()` and simply use the `{% url '' %}` tag to reverse the URL in the template (in place of `get_absolute_url()`).

Comment: `endfor` must be higher, before closing `tbody`, note there is a dangling `}` in the middle of `for`. Fix your html markup first.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I corrected the HTML file.

Comment: @elyas by this I m able to get URL but it does not display issueDate ,userName and returnDate

Answer (score 1):

Use following code in your template

```
<a href="{% url 'cylinderDetail' cy.pk %}">
```